1С Ввод адреса по КЛАДР
УТ 11.5 (upd: БСП 3.1.9.209)
Пытаюсь добавить в табличную часть поля с возможностью ввода адреса по КЛАДР.
Реализовано: загрузка адресного классификатора, поля табличной части типа строка (пока) и тестовая кнопка вызова типовой формы расширенного ввода адреса (предполагаю, что в ней идет подгонка по КЛАДРу).
Планирую: передать свойства тестовой кнопки полям табличной части и заполнять их данными из вызываемой типовой формы расширенного ввода адреса.
90% результатов поиска учат загружать кладр и создавать элементы формы, поэтому обращаюсь к живым людям: подскажите пожалуйста ваше видение. Я не прошу расжеванное решение (хоть и не откажусь), нужна хотя бы наводка, примерный план действий или просто мнение опытных специалистов, ибо чем больше углубляюсь- тем больше подозрения, что "воюю не туда". Спасибо за внимание

Какая у вас версия БСП?

Версия БСП: 3.1.9.209

В результате, что именно требуется? Хотите чтобы в строке таблицы при нажатии кнопки выбора открывалась типовая форма работы с адресом и когда там указывают данные, после закрытия адрес отформатированный по КЛАДР просто присвоить колонке в этой строке?

Или у вас колонками будет адрес разбит. Вроде как колонки "Город", "Улица" и т.п. ?

Вариант 1 (который без разбития на колонки). Если дословно, стараюсь сделать так:
-колонка "Пункт отправления" (готово);
-открытие типовой формы ввода адреса по клику на ячейку колонки "Пункт отправления" (готово);
-заполнение ячейки данными из типового ввода после его закрытия (в процессе).
Самый главный вопрос: имеет ли право на жизнь такое решение?

То есть, из типовой формы получить итоговый адрес в виде строки отформатированной согласно КЛАДР?

Да. Пока что я полагаю, что результат форматирования в типовой форме помещается в переменную или параметр, планирую "зацепить" его оттуда

upd: В "ПредставлениеАдреса" конечный результат помещается, уже получилось "цеплять" данные из вызываемой формы в форму-вызыватель, то есть идея почти реализована. Просто программирование- это парадигма, в которой одна задача имеет 100500 решений, и 100495 из них могут оказаться "грязными", поэтому и нуждаюсь в комментариях профессионалов

Значит задачу вы решили. Обычно в таких случаях можно аккуратно подсмотреть, как то или иное сделано в типовой конфигурации. Можно было бы глянуть, как заполняется адрес в каком-нибудь документе (например, заказ клиента, если включена функциональность доставки). Но предполагаю что там точно также. Формы выступает в роли некоего конструктора, которая по определенным правилам и справочной информации позволяет оформить адрес и в итоге его "выдает".
Тогда сами напишите ответ под вопросом, с кодом и разъяснением. Чтобы если кто-то попал сюда из поисковика, нашли ответ.

Еще нет. При вызове формы расширенного поля ввод адреса из ячейки таблицы не удается корректно передать данные в форму, если ячейка уже содержит адрес. Могу передать составные адреса в поля формы, но форма не понимает, что уже заполнена и при внесении изменений формирует "Представление адреса" на основе своего видения, то есть не учитывает данные, которые пришли программно при открытии

Вам нужно подсмотреть, как в типовых механизмах это сделано. Там же если открывать форму адреса (из поля где он был заполнен), форма же с полями открывается.
